# Jquery -Print Dialog Area :: Is exist plugin for printing jquery dialog content?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-dialog

I don't know well jquery ui.
Is exist plugin for printing jquery dialog content/some  code (Only print dialog content and not all webpage)

Thanks

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use [the `jqPrint` plugin for this](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/jqPrint), and [you can try a demo here](http://www.recoding.it/wp-content/uploads/demos/jqprint-demo.htm).

Usage is pretty simple:

```
$("#dialog").jqprint();
```

This opens the print dialog and you're all set.  In case you're wondering about the internals, [you can see the script here](http://plugins.jquery.com/files/jquery.jqprint.0.3.js_0.txt), it makes an `<iframe>`, copies your content over and triggers a print on it.  This isn't jQuery UI specific at all, just use the same selector as you use to define the dialog (or another, whatever you want to print!) and that's it.